# Lodash 2d array comparison for large data sets

Tags: javascript, lodash, office-js

I have a 2d array representing rows in a database. I'm using officeJS to load and manipulate the data in Excel. I update, insert, and delete rows. The challenge I'm facing is that I need to figure out the changed rows (inserted, deleted or updated) so that I can update only those rows in the database. I'm sending one query for the updated and inserted rows and one query for the deleted rows. I'm able to do this using lodash for data with 5000 rows and 10 columns. I'd like to scale this to a much larger data set and I'm wondering if there are any alternatives to what I'm currently doing. Below is the code I'm using to find the difference.

```
insertedOrUpdatedRows = _.differenceWith(modifiedData, originalData, _.isEqual);

deletedRows = _.differenceWith(originalData, modifiedData, compareFunction);

function compareFunction(a, b) {
    if(a[0] == b[0]) {
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

Sample data array

[ [1,data,data,data], 
[2,data,data,data] ]

The first element is the primary key.

Comment: This seems to be a pretty decent method.

Comment: Yea its failing for a larger dataset than 5000 rows and 10 columns. Is there any way I can process more data. Perhaps diving the data into chunks?

Comment: failing as in lodash is crashing.

Comment: One way to do this, is to use Lodash's chunk function. You could do something along the lines of `_.chunk(yourArray, yourArray.length/500`

Answer (score 0):

Because you have mentioned that your Javascript engine is crashing (which it should not, at 50,000 rows - so I would revisit the logic), I would recommend chunking out the data using Lodash's `_.chunk` function:

```
_.chunk(modifiedData, modifiedData.length/500).map({
  ...
  ...
});
```

Comment: Ok, I should add that I'm testing with 10 columns instead of 4 like showed in the sample array above. Obviously that's adding more overhead on lodash. Another approach I took was to stringify each of the rows before calling difference so that it can treat the entire row as one element. It works for 20,000 records and then the Excel addin browser crashes. I'll try the chunk method and give an update. Thanks for the help! Greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Ok im using the following logic. Not sure why its crashing at 50K rows. OriginalData and ModifiedData are in the format of the sample 2D array mentioned above.

```
var originalDataStrings = [];
var modifiedDataStrings = [];
var insertedOrUpdatedRows;

originalData.forEach(function(row){
  originalDataStrings.push(JSON.stringify(row));
});

modifiedData.forEach(function(row){
  modifiedDataStrings.push(JSON.stringify(row));
})

insertedOrUpdatedRows = _.differenceWith(modifiedDataStrings, originalDataStrings, _.isEqual);
console.log(insertedOrUpdatedRows);
```